# Error in angular-js while using angular-local-storage

Tags: angular-local-storage

This code in AngularJS using [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) throws an error at the console :

```
angular.module('myTodoApp').controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'localStorageService ', function($scope, localStorageService) {  

}]);
```

throws an error at the console :

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: localStorageService Provider <- localStorageService  <- MainCtrl
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=localStorageService%20Provider%20%3C-%20localStorageService%20%20%3C-%20MainCtrl
>       at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
>       at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4289:19
>       at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
>       at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4294:45
>       at getService (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
>       at invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4469:13)
>       at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4486:27)
>       at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9151:28
>       at link (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:977:26)
>       at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8789:9)

...but this runs perfectly fine!, may I know why?

```
angular.module('myTodoApp').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService) {

});
```

Comment: btw i have already added LocalStorageModule in app.js which loads prior to this code (which is in main.js)

Comment: Can you create a demo here or on JSFiddle or Plunker where to issue can be observed?

Comment: I hosted my app using rawgit -->  [my-todo-app](https://cdn.rawgit.com/hmandal/my-todo/16cb2d793a587b60681f143d902020a4f813734e/app/index.html#/)